# How to join tables with multiple columns relation?

Tags: mysql

i have a two tables - **Object** and **ObjectRelation**.

Object table:

```
╔════╦═════════════╗
║ id ║ name        ║
╠════╬═════════════╣
║ 1  ║ Client Side ║
╠════╬═════════════╣
║ 2  ║ Javascript  ║
╠════╬═════════════╣
║ 3  ║ Html        ║
╠════╬═════════════╣
║ 4  ║ Server Side ║
╠════╬═════════════╣
║ 5  ║ NodeJS      ║
╚════╩═════════════╝
```

ObjectRelation table:

```
╔════╦══════════╦════════════╗
║ id ║ parentid ║ childrenid ║
╠════╬══════════╬════════════╣
║ 1  ║ 1        ║ 2          ║
╠════╬══════════╬════════════╣
║ 2  ║ 1        ║ 3          ║
╠════╬══════════╬════════════╣
║ 3  ║ 4        ║ 5          ║
╚════╩══════════╩════════════╝
```

And here is what i would like to see as a result:

```
╔════╦═════════════╦════════════╗
║ id ║ parent      ║ children   ║
╠════╬═════════════╬════════════╣
║ 1  ║ Client Side ║ Javascript ║
╠════╬═════════════╬════════════╣
║ 2  ║ Client Side ║ Html       ║
╠════╬═════════════╬════════════╣
║ 3  ║ Server Side ║ Node JS    ║
╚════╩═════════════╩════════════╝
```

Is there any chance to do this in mySQL? 
I have tried a lot of combinations, but still without a result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can JOIN to the same table multiple times in a query as long as each reference has a different alias.

Answer (score 1):

Just simply `JOIN` the `Object` table twice.  Once for `parentid` and once for `childrenid`.

```
SELECT ObjectRelation.id, parent.name AS parent, children.name AS children
FROM ObjectRelation
JOIN Object AS parent ON parent.id=parentid
JOIN Object AS children ON children.id=childrenid
```

Comment: Well, thanks a lot, its working. To be honest, this was the first thing i tried, dont know why it wasnt working.